# My partial View is not showing error on validation and also on error my both view is getting opened up

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am facing problem in validation in  two of my partial view

**_partialA.cshtml**

```
@model demo3.Models.ModelA

   @using (Html.BeginForm("TEST", "Home"))    {

<h2>_partialA</h2>
<div>
     @Html.EditorFor(m => m.EmployeeId)  
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmployeeId) 
</div>
<div>
     @Html.EditorFor(m => m.EmployeeName)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmployeeName) 
</div>
 <input class="mainbutton" type="submit" value="TEST"/><br />
 }
```

and another partial view is this

**_partialB.cs.html**

```
 @model demo3.Models.ModelB
      @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateAgreement", "Home"))
            {

<h2>_partialB</h2>
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Comapny)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Comapny)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FisacalYear)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FisacalYear)  </div>
  <input class="mainbutton" type="submit" value="CreateAgreement"/><br />
 }
```

This is my controller code

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateAgreement(ModelB modelb)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Start", modelb);
        }
        return View("Start", modelb);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TEST(ModelA modela)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Start", modela);
        }
        return View("Start", modela);
    }
    public ActionResult Start()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult FirstView()
    {
        ModelA objA = new ModelA();
        return PartialView("_partialA", objA);
    }
    public ActionResult SecondView()
    {
        ModelB objB = new ModelB();
        return PartialView("_partialB", objB);
    }
```

Now i am not getting any error message on click of button..and another thing..is my both view are getting opened up..on click of button..how to prevent that?

Comment: You *just* asked a question very similar.  Are you even attempting to figure out anything yourself?

Comment: where i have written if else in above code

Comment: And ya i am trying to figure out..how to do validation in partial views..If it is coded like above @Ekonomik

Comment: Do your models have validation attributes?  Have you set breakpoints in your code to see if you are actually getting into the post methods? Typically, more than one form on a page is bad, unless you are handling posts client-side and disabling default behavior.

Comment: yes I have required data annotations in my model..and i am getting into my post methods

Answer (score 1):

To validate your form check these steps :

1) Into your partial view set the Layout to `null` :

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

2) add these scripts before the form :

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateAgreement", "Home"))
 {
```

3) add the Html validation :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateAgreement", "Home"))
 {
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

4) If you have annotation into your model and the error message it will works.

Comment: yes it is working...but my first partial view is getting displayed..instead of my index page..which contains anchor tags